# Handlebars templates - Rendering data inside if statement

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, template-engine

To the handlebars (version 1.0.0-rc.3) template I am passing two variables, one is the json and the other one is the string containing the current language on site.

```
self.template = template({ data: self.model, lang:self.lang });
```

Then inside my template file I am having issues with displaying lang variable inside the if statement. So the structure of my template is the following:

```
 {{#each data}}    
     {{#if this.title}} 
          ...some html...
           <a class='links' href="{{../lang}}/work/{{this.id}}">View Project</a> 
          ...some html...
      {{/if}}
 {{/each}}
```

I am unable to access the lang variable only inside the if statement and outside is being shown properly...
Please advise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution by creating a handlebars helper function:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper( 'language'
                           , function() {
                                return self.lang;           
                             });
```

Then in the template I can use `{{language}}` where ever needed.